# valueFormatter executes before useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a Country table on db and I want to render this on a grid. The table looks like below

```
CountryName  Country3AlpCode CurrencyId 
Argentina     ARG            7
Austria       AUT            49


and i have a Currency table on db also:

Id CurrencyAlphaCode CurrencyName
7  ARS               Argentine peso
49 EUR               Euro
```

I want to render the country table to a grid and instead currency, i need currencyAlphaCode. I declared two states for lists of datas and inside use effect I fetched them with API calls and set them to states. Passing country definitions as RowData props. Inside column definitions, i used valueFormatter as below and it doesn't work. It still renders currencyId instead currencyAlphaCode

```
 const [countryDefinitions, setCountryDefinitions] = useState<Country[]>();
 const [currencyCodeList, setCurrencyCodeList] = useState<Currency[]>();

useEffect(() => {
    const onStartup = async () => {
      const currencyCodeList = await commonAPI.get<Currency[]>("currency");
      const countryList = await commonAPI.get<Country[]>("country");
      setCurrencyCodeList(currencyCodeList);
      setCountryDefinitions(countryList);
    };

    onStartup();
  }, []);


 const columnDefs: any =
    [
      {
        field: "currencyId",
        headerName: "Currency",
        valueFormatter: (params: any) => {
          console.log(currencyCodeList);  // returns undefined
          return currencyCodeList?.find((currency) => {
            return currency.id === params.value;
          })?.currencyAlphaCode;
        }
      },
```